# Constructing an array from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm getting a JSON using

```
 $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/test_json/", function(data) {

});
```

Output looks like this.

```
{"items":[{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7}]}
```

After some trimming

```
data = JSON.stringify(data);
data = data.substring(9);
data = data.substring(0, data.length - 1);
data = data.replace(/[{}]/g, " ");  
console.log(data);
```

It looks like this

```
["1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7]
```

I would like to "deconstruct" (?) this as to remove all keys so that only values remain.

```
[1 ,2 ,3 , 4 , 5 , 6 ,7]
```

I'm going to use this to draw charts. So for exampel that could be my data that I'm going to pass to my chart library.

Comment: I think the approach is long if the whole point is to just get the values. You could iterate through the "data" object. If you must have it in a separate Array, arr[], $.each(data, function(key, val){ arr.push(val) }) would work

Comment: why would you convert it to a string first? This has been asked almost daily on SO, have you searched? You'll find answers aplenty

Comment: Why is it an object in the first place if the keys apparently do not have any meaning? I'm assuming you control the generation of that JSON data, can't you output an array to begin with? I'll also echo the sentiments above: don't convert an object/array into a string and then manipulate the string! You have a perfectly manipulable and traversable data structure already, you just need to traverse it.

Comment: Because I can't substring if I don't convert it, right?
I do not control how it's created , they way I get it is the way I have to handle it.

Comment: "To substring" is the wrong approach to begin with. You *loop*, you don't substring.

Comment: Why does your object start with `1`?

Comment: Is the *order* of the values important? Objects are not guaranteed to be ordered at all. You either need some very careful looping to ensure you retain the given order, or the value should *really really* be an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't start "trimming" your JSON like that. Just parse it and process it like any other object.

```
var json = '{"items":[{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7}]}';
```

Parse your JSON to a JS object (tho I note that you're using jQuery to get the data so this will be parsed already, so you can skip this step):

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Grab the first element of `items` (an array) which is an another object:

```
var items = obj.items[0];
```

Grab the item keys with `Object.keys()` and use that array to return the values with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
var vals = Object.keys(items).map(function (el) {
  return items[el];
}); // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7hmkxnL/2/)

**EDIT**

So now you have some new data:

```
var json = '{"items":[{"sum":188700.75},{"sum":633927.98},{"sum":7000},{"sum":65169.26},{"sum":17114.67},{"sum":252340.96},{"sum":1073246.73}]}'
```

The following JS will grab the value of `sum` from each object:

```
var items = obj.items;
var vals = items.map(function (el) {
  return el.sum;
});
```

**Output**

```
[ 188700.75, 633927.98, 7000, 65169.26, 17114.67, 252340.96, 1073246.73 ]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L7hmkxnL/6/)

Comment: Yeah but it will be an array of keys while I think OP needs an array of values.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't spot that. Fixed.

Comment: Yes Andy that is it, ty very much!!

Comment: Never let me catch you "trimming" your JSON like that again, ok? :)

Comment: Don't put your hopes on a fools back. :x 
Will this also function the same if I write words instead of numbers like so
http://jsfiddle.net/L7hmkxnL/5/

Comment: That will work for the first object in that array, but now you've got multiple objects. Let me work on a solution for you.

Comment: It was my mistake for not providing a good example, I'm sorry for that :/
I really appreciate your help ,same as anyones elses.

Answer (score 0):

You have json data why need stringify it ?

```
var input = data.items[0]

    var arr = $.map(input,function(v){
     return v;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach from what have been told you.

You don't need to trim the data.

```
var json  = JSON.parse(data);
var items = json.items[0];
```

And you don't need to remove keys, you can send the values into another array.

```
var listOfItems = [];

for(var key in items)
   listOfItems.push(items[key]);
```

Comment: @Andy the only thing needed to be repaired is `json.items` into `json.items[0]` than it works as expected. ;)

Comment: Then you should edit your answer because, as it stands, it's useless.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to extract the values, you can do it by accessing it like this:

```
var obj = data.items[0];
```

Your variable `obj` will look like this:

```
{"1":1,"2":2,"3":3,"4":4,"5":5,"6":6,"7":7}
```

Then I guess you will have to iterate on this object to make it an array:

```
var arr = [];
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    arr.push(obj[key]);
  }
}
```

The variable `arr` will then contain the elements you wish.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kgo6uu5d/)